# html label as a button - I need to be able to disable using angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a label thats a button. I need to be able to disable it. ng-dialog doesnt work. If i use ng-diable it shows disabled, but the button is still functional. Which is bad. The label button is still clickable. Yes, i could use a regular button, but for this situation I need to use the label button.

```
<label type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block hist-button" 
   id="importHistEditButton" ng-controller="ImportHistoryController" 
   ng-click="getImportHistory(editSource.sourceId); showDialog();">
<span class="icon-plus"></span> Import History
```

Is there a way to disable the label button so its not clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS to make the label not clickable.

```
<style type="text/css">
    label.btn.hist-button {
       pointer-events: none;
    }
<style>
```

This works well in most browsers except IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this bit of CSS that looks for the "disabled" data attribute ng-disabled is adding.  Here is an example:

```css
label[disabled]{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<label type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block hist-button" 
   id="importHistEditButton" ng-controller="ImportHistoryController" 
   onClick="alert('hello')" disabled>Try to click me! </label>
```